# Problem with Chrome headless from CLI: empty PDF and error "Failed to serialize document: Uncaught"

Tags: linux, google-chrome, headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

My web application generates a PDF from an HTML page via Google Chrome 76.0.3809.100 headless on Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch). My call looks like this:

```
google-chrome --headless --ignore-certificate-errors --hide-scrollbars --print-to-pdf='mypdf.pdf' --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --no-sandbox --virtual-time-budget=60000 https://example.com/mypage.html
```

Everything works perfectly... about 9 times out of 10. But sometime I got an empty PDF.

I thought it was a bug in my code, so I tried to run the same command from the command line directly. I also added `--dump-dom` to exclude the PDF generation and display the HTML on the console. Again, about 9 times out of 10 it works, one... it doesn't.

When it doesn't, I get this error:

```
[0814/090047.461433:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(434)] Failed to serialize document: Uncaught
```

Well, actually this is my full console output, but all the other messages are there also when it runs OK, so I don't think they matter:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
[0814/090046.673042:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(107)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Shared memory region is not valid
[0814/090046.674622:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[0814/090046.736342:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(969)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for example.com failed err=-8102
[0814/090047.461433:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(434)] Failed to serialize document: Uncaught
[0814/090047.474334:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 3 ms for network service
```

Ok, so back to "my bad" route. I switched `https://example.com/mypage.html` to `https://google.com` and... lo and behold! Same "sometime" error!

I'm fresh out of ideas, even more since I cannot replicate the behaviour in a consistent manner: sometime it works, sometime it doesn't.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I reported this to the Chromium devs as [Issue 993686](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=993686). It was recognized as a bug in Chromium.

As a workaround, I removed som aync-loaded fonts I had in my CSS and now it works 10/10.

Comment: I can't remove fonts so one dumb workaround is to keep downloading until the pdf is non-blank, since the bug appears random.

Comment: It's 2022 (well nearly 2023) and the bug is still there